# Garageband still taking up space in High Sierra

Tags: audio, storage, spaces, garageband, macos

Garageband is taking up nearly 25 GB of space under Music Creation when I look at "Manage" storage on my Macbook Air running High Sierra. I have deleted every file for Garageband, including Apple Loops and the preferences and containers and any files that were suggested online in various help lists, including this one. I deleted all files and emptied the trash and restarted several times, and it STILL shows 24.93 GB of space used under Music Creation for GarageBand instruments and lessons. I don't use GarageBand nor do I use LogicPro, so I would like to free up that much space. Any ideas on what to do next? This is infuriating, I've tried all the suggestions, what I am missing?

Answer (score 2):

These are all the GarageBand folders...make sure they are all empty.
Also, **quit and restart Storage Management after** you have cleared those folders to see the changes or even a reboot, might help sort some other things out. Hope this helps...

1. /Applications/GarageBand.app
2. /Library/Application Support/Garageband
3. /Library/Application Support/Logic
4. /Library/Audio
5. ~/Library/Application Support/Garageband
6. ~/Library/Application Support/Audio

Comment: Thanks, Frehley666. Sadly, I had already tried deleting all of the folders you mention, in both the general library and in my user library. And I restarted several times after deleting and trying various options. It still shows 24.93 GB being used for GarageBand instruments and lessons. This is so weird!

Comment: I submitted an edit to fix the directory path for the `/Audio` folder, it's actually: `/Library/Audio`, and I found a decent amount of files in mine. But far more were found in `/Library/Application Support/GarageBand`.